# Android reading text file shows text as gibrige

Tags: android, text, readfile

I have a srt file (subtitle file) which im trying to read in android, opening the srt file on my pc with notepad++ shows gibrige text, but notepad++ has an option to read file as windows-1256 which fix this issue, I was wondering how can I do this in Android ? 
Also is there a way to automatically choose how to read the file in Android so it shows the actual letters no matter what language is written in the text ?
I tried this code but it didn't help:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(theFile), "Windows-1256");
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(r);
try {
  String line;
  while ((line = buffered.readLine()) != null) {
    // handle each line
  }
} finally {
  buffered.close();
}
```

Comment: what is `gibrige text` ?

Comment: a text that you can't understand